# Strange Hidden Word In Question

Tags: support, questions, edits, editor

I was going to clean up [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218692/postgresql-with-wamp) earlier, but I found something odd: The question begins with "Dear," but when you edit the question it's not there.  I forwent editing to not hide a potential bug.

Why isn't the text showing up in edit?

Comment: Probably due to auto-fluff removal.

Comment: The answer is caching: [Edit source differs from question view or are we each others friends now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123981)

Comment: If you just save the edit (with the Dear removed), does it work?  If not, this might still be a bug (what if the only thing wrong was the Dear?), if a minor one.

Comment: I'm not sure how to test that at this point.  I tried a rollback and, as expected, it didn't bring back the phantom word.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Certain words like "hi", "dear" etc. are automatically removed if they appear at the start of a question.

This was not part of the original features of Stack Overflow so there will be questions that predate this feature that still have these "fluff" words (thanks [BradleyDotNET](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1783619/bradleydotnet)). However, when you edit the post, the "auto-fluff removal" kicks in and deletes the unnecessary verbiage.

In fact the text may have already been removed from the post, but the HTML used to display the post hasn't been regenerated. It's heavily cached for speed. So when you go to edit the post the HTML is recreated and the word disappears.

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  I removed the bug tag from my question.

Comment: This is not quite accurate: the text _is_ already removed in the DB, but the contents of the post are cached, and only re-fetched when the edit happens. An unimportant difference, but the Meta.SE post I linked above explains the whole thing.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - Oh. I thought it would only happen on a resubmit of the text.

Comment: Background: This feature was added in June 2011. See [the original post by Jeff Atwood about this feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989) (to question *[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950)*).

Comment: Sorry to bother you with cross-site clarification, but is your answer (that "automatic removal" part) applicable on  other network sites as well? For example, [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/revisions/125545/1) still has that "Hi" fluff intact.