# First line disappears when posting question

Tags: support, questions, signatures

I have written [Why was my answer deleted? I think it should be undeleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325589/what-can-i-do-if-my-answer-was-deleted-by-a-moderator-unfairly-at-all) starting with

> Dear Sir or Madam,

but this line disappeared and editing doesn't help. What's the problem?

Comment: See [This](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307698/5240004) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: You're not writing a letter, you're posting on SE. It's likely this was auto-removed by the SE software algorithm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior - Site rules state not to use signatures, taglines, or greetings.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is you're adding unnecessary noise to your posts. It is getting stripped out by the [automatic system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989), otherwise it should be edited out by hand by an editor.

Your posts are not a letter. Or a forum post. Or a chat room.

You should write as if you were making an encyclopedia or a textbook. That's much closer to what Stack Overflow is modeled after.